# Draw Something loading UIActivity indicator view

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

In the awesome app Draw Something, when you click on something and the page is loading, a custom uiactivity indicator view is pulled up where a pencil moves in a (non circular) path in a loop.  How would I start to set this up in my own iPhone App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create your own [animating "`UIImageView`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImageView/startAnimating) object (which you could call instead of UIActivityIndicatorView) or you could subclass "`UIActivityIndicatorView`" and do your own drawing (yech; I'd say the first method would be the way I would prefer to do it).